# Prepopulating a Django model with large amounts of data

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm trying to load a list of Rolling Stone's top 500 songs - as well as other characteristics such as their rank, description, cover image, ect. - into a Django database so that I can display a random song each day on m. I managed to scrape the list from the site well enough, but I'm having trouble loading the list into the database as a single instance of the model I created, as opposed to 500. I tried writing a migration to do it for me, but I don't think it worked properly. I've attached the code below, let me know if you see anything:

```
# Create function to actally load data into table
def loadSongs(apps, schema_editor):
    # Initialize counter to iterate through site pages, initialize album rankings, create model, then scrape pages one by one
    #top500songs = Songs()
    links = np.arange(1,11,1)
    rank = 500
    songList = []
    for link in links:
        # Get and store link to page, initialize lists to store data values
        page = requests.get('https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-lists/500-greatest-songs-of-all-time-151127/?list_page=' + str(link))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
        # Look for song entries on the page, stored as articles with "item" class. Sleep for a bit to prevent overloading server
        songs = soup.find_all('article', class_='c-list__item') 
        sleep(randint(2,5))
        # Store essential info in each entry for use in site
        for song in songs:
            # Store the songs rank, then then prepare the rank variable for the next song
            top500songs = Songs()
            top500songs.rank = rank
            rank = rank-1
            # Store the name of the song and the artist, being careful to ignore the ads that also have the article tag
            name = song.header.h3.text if song.header else 'ad'
            if name != 'ad':
                artist,title = name.split(',',1) # this still leaves the quotes around the title. look for ways to remove them
                top500songs.artist = artist
                top500songs.title = title
            # Store the album cover, again ignoring ads. Designate songs without a single cover
            cover = song.figure.find('div', class_='c-crop c-crop--ratio-1x1') if song.figure else 'ad'
            if cover != 'ad':
                coverPic = cover.img['src'] if cover.img else 'no image'
                top500songs.cover = coverPic
            # Store the songs description from the rolling stone page, avoiding ads.
            describe = song.main.div.find_all('p') if song.main else 'ad'
            if describe != 'ad':
                drop,writer,producer,releaseInfo = describe[0].text.split(":",3) if describe[0].text != '*' else describe[1].text.split(":",3)
                top500songs.writers = writer
                top500songs.producers = producer
                top500songs.releaseInfo = releaseInfo
                scrip = describe[1].text if describe[0].text != '*' else describe[2].text
                top500songs.description = scrip
            songList.append(top500songs)
    Songs.objects.bulk_create(songList)'
```

Songs model:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cover = models.ImageField()
    writers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    producers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    releaseInfo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question and add the contents of `models.py`?

Comment: hedgie, I've added the definition of Songs to my post

Comment: Besides the use of the word "Songs" to denote a single song is a bit confusing, I don't see anything wrong with this code. Also, an (initial) migration is a nice place to put this code. Have you tried inserting `print()` statements in the inner loop to see what it's doing?